# OnClick Method Scope

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Somehow I can see the onClick Methods from other activities in my project. I do not know why, but it seems like they are set global.

Now I have a `onButtonOkClick` method in my current activity and an `onButtonOkClick` in the previous activity and I get a `NullPointerException` because it tries to access the one from the previous activity.

Where can I configure that scope? Apparently the onClick methods  have to be public also?

```
public void onButtonOkClick(View view) {
    // CODE
}
```

I can also see all elements like `EditText` and `Buttons` from other Activities in the resources (`R.id`). Maybe I misconfigured this somewhere?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

**The code**

The code that causes the error is not mine. It just happens when I click on the "OK" button. It happens in the handler created by the Android SDK . (Of course, it can't access the method of an Activity that does not exist anymore!)

**Where do I see the onClick methods from other Activities**

I am using AndroidStudio. One can configure the onClick listener in the designer (you can do so too in the layout XML). I can see the onClick method from the previous Activity, but not the one from the current Activity which has the same name. (Both are called `onButtonOkClick`)

I can actually see all onButtonClick from all Activities. In the past I just named them differently but first of all this is a very VERY uggly approach (and I hope it is not by Android design), and second is that the names are getting more and more complicated.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a screenshot from AndroidStudio. As you can see there are handlers from several activities listed and I can not name them the same.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post the stacktrace for the NullPointerException and the code that causes the error.

Comment: "I can also see all elements like EditText and Buttons from other Activities in the resources (R.id). Maybe I misconfigured this somewhere?" No, this is not a problem. All of the ids for every view in your XML layout files will be generated in the `R` class.

Comment: Show more code - how exactly is one `onClick` listener method accessible from another `Activity`?

Comment: I have updated the question. I can't show you my code inside the button because it doesn't even get executed. I can see all other onClick methods in the designer of android Studio. If you need more informations just ask.

Comment: it's normal to see all R.xx.xx value of XML files in all activities,
but i would like to ask if you use onClick as btn.setListener... or you are defining it at the layout xml file?

Comment: im not familar with AndroidStudio and setting the listener in the xml, but i guess AndroidStudio just offers you all possible functions, even those which are not accessible. You probably can only take those functions, which are in the activity, where you are inflating the xml

Comment: I hope so... It is a very ugly thing to have everything public. There must be a way to clean this up.